# knex/postgresql connection ends after insert operation

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, knex.js

Running a node/express server with knex configured to work with a local postgresql database. I have an endpoint which triggers an update of two tables, but the connection silently dies when inserting data into the first table -- no errors are thrown, nothing is caught in my try/catch block, even though the insert actually happens. I'm checking against existing db entries to pre-filter new entries, so when the function is run again nothing new gets added for the first table, and then the second table's insert runs with normal behavior (connection stays alive, function finishes executing and is able to return a response).

These are very basic insert operations using knex syntax:

```
const add = (datasets) => {
  db("datasets")
    .insert(datasets)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("result: ", result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error", err.message);
    });
};
```

This behavior is seen whether a single entry or multiples are added to the table, and the logging of `result` returns the successful message of rows affected, etc. This exact same syntax is used for the other table insert and the connection stays alive when that query is made.

Is there something I'm not seeing in how the knex/pg connection could die without throwing an error or any feedback at all?

I've played around with other pool/timeout settings in the knexfile as well, but reverted back to the basic config when nothing else worked:

```
development: {
    client: "postgresql",
    connection: {
      host: "localhost",
      database: "postgres",
      user: "postgres",
      password: "postgres",
    },
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations",
      directory: "./models/migrations/",
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: "./models/seeds/",
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the parts where `add` is called. Also that function should return the promise so that caller could wait that inserting is ready.

```
const add = (datasets) => {
  return db("datasets")
    .insert(datasets)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("result: ", result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error", err.message);
    });
};
```

Though that doesn't explain the behavior you are observing. If you are calling the `add` correctly you should see some kind result log.

You can set `DEBUG=knex:*` environment variable before running the app to see what kind of queries are actually made by the application.